# losing indexing in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I run into a rare situation when creating and deleting indexes on a table, let say that we create the following table:

```
create table my_table(id serial primary key, label text);
```

As this table contains a **primary key** we got our first index, in top of that lets add another one:

```
create index my_index on my_table(label);
```

And now some data...

```
insert into my_table (label) values ('alpha');
insert into my_table (label) values ('beta');
insert into my_table (label) values ('sigma');
insert into my_table (label) values ('sigma');
insert into my_table (label) values ('alpha');
insert into my_table (label) values ('gamma');
```

At this point we have two indexes working perfectly as we can see on the following **sql explains**

```
explain analyze select * from my_table where label = 'alpha';

Bitmap Heap Scan on my_table  (cost=4.20..13.67 rows=6 width=36) 
                              (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=2 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (label = 'alpha'::text)
  Heap Blocks: exact=1
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_index  (cost=0.00..4.20 rows=6 width=0) 
                                     (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=2 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (label = 'alpha'::text)
Planning time: 0.084 ms
Execution time: 0.046 ms
```

The issue is that if I touch the indexes at this point either by adding a third one or recreating *my_index* I get painful **sequential scans**, for example:

```
drop index my_index;
create index my_index on my_table(label);

-- executing the same search againg
explain analyze select * from my_table where label = 'alpha';

Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..1.08 rows=1 width=36) 
                      (actual time=0.025..0.026 rows=2 loops=1)
  Filter: (label = 'alpha'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 4
Planning time: 0.111 ms
Execution time: 0.036 ms
```

My understanding is that whenever I create an index the data on the table should be indexed *-locking all write operations in the mean time-* and that is not happening for some reason I ignore, does anyone know why this is ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean, painful? It was faster the second time, wasn't it?

Comment: Hi @melpomene, the table contains only 6 elements, the question is more about why the first search was a Bitmap Heap Scan and the second one was a Seq Scan. Imagine that you add 40 MM entries on that table and the perform searches again. do postgres will use then an indexed search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot draw any conclusions about the use of indexes in a table with several rows. Prepare test data with at least a few hundred thousand rows, e.g.:

```
drop table if exists my_table cascade;
create table my_table(id serial primary key, label text);
create index my_index on my_table(label);
insert into my_table (label)
select generate_series(1, 500000)::text
```

Update the table statistics before applying explain:

```
vacuum analyze my_table;
```

Run explain:

```
explain analyze select * from my_table where label = '123456';

                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using my_index on my_table  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.288..0.290 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (label = '123456'::text)
 Planning time: 80.753 ms
 Execution time: 0.476 ms
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very educational for me :)

Comment: You're welcome. For my own tests I use a special table and a function that generates random texts. It is important not to forget about `vacuum analyze` after each modification of a table, constraint, index or a larger change of data.